# PyDev 5.3 and Eclipse Neon 4.6 - pydevd.py loacation (OSx)

Tags: pydev

I switched from Eclipse Mars to Eclipse Neon today. The Pydev plugin was not installed at the place where it was in Eclipse Mars (**/Applications/eclipse/cpp-neon/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins**).

Does anyone know where the pydevd.py is located on OsX.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to know where the PyDev debugger is located is by opening a PyDev editor, writing pydevd and requesting a code completion just showing the templates (ctrl space twice)... A template for creating a programmatic breakpoint will be shown (and it adds the debugger to the PYTHONPATH, so you can see where it's located).

Comment: I dound it here: Users/name/. p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev_5.
 3.1.201610311318/pysrc    thanks